# How to redirect pages in ASP MVC using AngularJS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I went through the process of starting a new ASP.NET MVC no-user authentication process, and have already began integrating AngularJS with C# code.

My `_ViewStart.cshtml` uses `_Layout.cshtml` to `@RenderBody()` for each of my Views found under Views->Home. I have my two views, `Index.cshtml` and `SignUp.cshtml`.

In the Index partial view, I have a form that has an action controlled by this AngularJS function:

```
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $location, LoginService) {
    $scope.LoginData = {
        CID: '',
        Email: ''
    };

    $scope.Login = function ($window) {
        $scope.Submitted = true;
        if ($scope.IsFormValid) {
            LoginService.GetUser($scope.LoginData).then(function (d) {
                if (d.data.CID != null) {
                    loginCID = d.data.CID;
                    loginEmail = d.data.Email;
                    $scope.Message = "Successfully logged in. Welcome " + d.data.CID;
                    $location.path("/Home/SignUp");
                }
                else {
                    alert("Invalid Creds");
                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```

I've omitted in included any extra code that wasn't entirely necessary for this question so extra variables/factories/services have been excluded. The code all works except for this line:

```
$location.path("/Home/SignUp");
```

Once the form is filled out, `$scope.Message` changes to what's in the if statement, and the URL changed from `http://localhost:61660/` to `http://localhost:61660/Home/SignUp` But the partial view for Index still shows. Meaning, I'm still seeing `Index.cshtml` being rendered in the body and not `SignUp.cshtml`. How can I change this to actually redirect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this approach instead of `$location.path("/Home/SignUp")`:

```
window.location.pathname = 'Home/SignUp';
```

It is caused, because angular intercepts `$location`'s redirections and process them by means of own's routing infrastructure, **preventing** your's expected behavior.

Comment: I just ran into a problem. If I place a `console.log('test')` inside the `SignUpController.js` nothing is output on the console when it navigates over.

Comment: Try to go to this page directly from browser and check will log's message appear at console or not.